# IBM Watson Tone Analyzer: Error 403 - How can I overcome this Problem?

Tags: api, websphere, ibm-watson

I am currently pulling requests from IBM Watson Tone Analyzer. I have a Lite account, and I have not exceeded the API limit.

I have been getting this error message for hours, despite repeating my request again and again.

Does anyone have any idea how to overcome this? Thank you.

```
ApiException: Error: Forbidden, Code: 403 , X-global-transaction-id: f3325ba4-eafa-4002-a09a-ff037fc42df5
```

Comment: Did your requests ever work, or have you only ever seen 403 errors?

Comment: My requests have worked before, but suddenly gave me error.
However, it worked again after I restarted my computer, tried a different pin / refreshed my worksheet. Either of the above method worked :) I suspect it was the pin issue.

Comment: [Fleur Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15673731) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67139860) saying "Have you used your API key and url? [...]"